# Changing the background color of a single item of a dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="list" >
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list a');
  $('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list a');
```

**CSS**

```
ul.list {
  height: 100%;

  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
ul.list li a{
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  padding:0!important;
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
  text-decoration: none;

}
ul.list li:hover  {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/persiaprince/Lem4mu68/2)

The main difference between the jsfiddle and my own code is that I'm running a for loop in my script which reads a database and adds items to my list. Like so:

`for(var i = 1; i < dbLength; i++ ){
          text = res[1].values[i];
          $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.list a')
        }`

Each item on the list is a hyperlink to another page. I want each item on the list to have its background color changed when the mouse is hovered over the item. My issue is that when I hover my mouse all the items change their background color. For some reason it works perfectly fine for changing individual text color though. How do I change only the background color of the selected items?

Comment: Change how you target the `:hover` to `ul.list li a li:hover` since you want to target the `li` within your anchors `a` **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/hvmmsvua/

Comment: You probably do not want to append the list items INSIDE the anchor as it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding your list items INSIDE the existing list item and its anchor. Therefore the `li` selectors you are using are applied to all the created and contained items. This is error-prone and invalid HTML.

[image]

Change

```
$('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list a');
$('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list a');
```

to

```
$('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list');
$('<li />', {html: "testing loop"}).appendTo('ul.list');
```

or in case of your loop:

```
for( var i = 1; i < dbLength; i++ ){
  text = res[1].values[i];
  $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.list')
}
```

and you should be fine.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lem4mu68/3/)

**EDIT:**
In order to make every list element an anchor, use this:

```
for( var i = 1; i < dbLength; i++ ){
  var text = res[1].values[i];
  var newElem = '<li><a href="#">' + text + '</a><li />';
  $(newElem).appendTo('ul.list')
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: Shoot, actually now my list items no longer act as hyperlinks.

Comment: @persiaprince of course not, they are not supposed to. Add a new anchor (`<a>`) into every list element if you want them to be anchors/hyperlinks.

Comment: @persiaprince i have added the respective code change to the answer.

Comment: How can I do that if I don't know how big my list is going to be beforehand?

Comment: @persiaprince see last part of my answer

Comment: so that fixed the link problem, but now its only appending the "link text" to my list instead of the {html: text}).appendTo('ul.list')

Answer (score 2):

I updated your jsfiddle with a working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/persiaprince/Lem4mu68/2/

Your issue was selecting wrong element. You have 2 list items inside an anchor tag, and you were selecting list item which was a parent of that anchor tag.

```
ul.list li a li {
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  padding:0!important;
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
  text-decoration: none;

}
ul.list li a li:hover  {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change css

`ul.list li:hover` to `ul.list li a:hover`

change javascript

```
    for(var i = 1; i < dbLength; i++ ){
      text = res[1].values[i];
      $('<a />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.list li')
    }
```

This is working on your jsfiddle.